# How to check given string(code line) is php commented?

Tags: php

I read php file and that file content(some code line) store in php array as line by line

my php file line array

```
$old_line_arr = new array(
                           "define ( 'name', '' );"
                           "//define ( 'age', '' );"   
                           "   //define ( 'ID', '' );"
                           )
```

i want to check given line array is commented

```
isComment($old_line_arr[0]){
  echo $old_line_arr[0].'commented';
}
```

how can i write isComment function? Is there any build in php function for check given php like is commented or not commented.

Comment: You can [tokenize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) the string and inspect what kind of token(s) you got.

Comment: The issue with storing each line in an array is that it's hard to detect when a line is commented between `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: I've created a simple command that finds PHPStorm-commented-code easily: https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/how-to-easily-protected-your-code-base-from-commented-php-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `function` like this

```
function isComment($str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $first_two_chars = substr($str, 0, 2);
    $last_two_chars = substr($str, -2);
    return $first_two_chars == '//' || substr($str, 0, 1) == '#' || ($first_two_chars == '/*' && $last_two_chars == '*/');
}
```

Example: `echo isComment($old_line_arr[0]) ? 'comment' : 'not a comment';`

Comment: There's also the case of using `#` to comment.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty, may need some more error handling code for various conditions:

```
$string = "//define('ID', '');";

$tokens = token_get_all("<?php $string");

if ($tokens[1][0] == T_COMMENT) {
    // it's a comment
} else {
    // it's not
}
```